# List of categories with data based on two array of objects with same parent ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have two array of objects that are linked by a parent ID. I am trying to make a list of categories, and in each category is a set of data that corresponds to its respective category. It will be a header (category), then a set of buttons (data). The header data has an ID, the button data has a parentId based on the headers regular ID
ex. Category 1 ID = 62, Button 3 parent ID = 62.

I need to create a way to display each category with its respective data.

Category array:

```
[
   {
      "categoryName":"Category 1",
      "id":62,
      "parentId":0,
      "txt":"category1"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Category 2",
      "id":60,
      "parentId":0,
      "txt":"category2"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Category 3",
      "id":61,
      "parentId":0,
      "txt":"category3"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Category 4",
      "id":59,
      "parentId":0,
      "txt":"category4"
   }
]
```

Data array:

```
 [
  {
      "categoryName":"Button 1",
      "id":29,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":60,
      "txt":"button1"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Button 2",
      "id":31,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":61,
      "txt":"button2"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Button 3",
      "id":35,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":62,
      "txt":"button3"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Button 4",
      "id":37,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":62,
      "txt":"button4"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Button 5",
      "id":39,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":59,
      "txt":"button5"
   },
   {
      "categoryName":"Button 6",
      "id":41,
      "isChecked":false,
      "parentId":59,
      "txt":"button6"
   }
]
```

Looking for something like this??:

```
  [
    {
      categoryName: 'Category 1',
      id: 62,
      parentId: 0,
      txt: 'category1',
      children: [
        {
          categoryName: 'Category 1',
          id: 62,
          parentId: 0,
          txt: 'category1',
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Category 2',
      id: 60,
      parentId: 0,
      txt: 'category2',
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Category 3',
      id: 61,
      parentId: 0,
      txt: 'category3',
    },
    {
      categoryName: 'Category 4',
      id: 59,
      parentId: 0,
      txt: 'category4',
    },
  ]
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate the expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// categories is your top level categories object and data is the children you posted
const tree = categories.map(category => {
   return { 
     ...category,
     children: data.filter(child => child.parentId === category.id)
   }
})
```

What we do here is first loop over the top level categories. We then return the category untouched, but merged with the `children` property, which is set to the items in the second dataset which have a matching `parentId` to the top level category currently being processed in that first loop.

Answer (score 1):

The expected result your provided isn't consistent. But I think I can work with that.

```js
var arr_cat = [{
    "categoryName": "Category 1",
    "id": 62,
    "parentId": 0,
    "txt": "category1"
  }, {
    "categoryName": "Category 2",
    "id": 60,
    "parentId": 0,
    "txt": "category2"
  }, {
    "categoryName": "Category 3",
    "id": 61,
    "parentId": 0,
    "txt": "category3"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Category 4",
    "id": 59,
    "parentId": 0,
    "txt": "category4"
  }
];

var arr_data = [{
    "categoryName": "Button 1",
    "id": 29,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 60,
    "txt": "button1"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Button 2",
    "id": 31,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 61,
    "txt": "button2"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Button 3",
    "id": 35,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 62,
    "txt": "button3"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Button 4",
    "id": 37,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 62,
    "txt": "button4"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Button 5",
    "id": 39,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 59,
    "txt": "button5"
  },
  {
    "categoryName": "Button 6",
    "id": 41,
    "isChecked": false,
    "parentId": 59,
    "txt": "button6"
  }
]

// first group categories by their id's for easy access.
var obj = arr_cat.reduce(function(agg, item) {
  agg[item.id] = item;
  return agg;
}, {});

// then assign each data to the relevant sub-object
arr_data.forEach(function(item) {
  if (obj[item.parentId]) {
    obj[item.parentId].children = obj[item.parentId].children || []
    obj[item.parentId].children.push(item);
  }
});

// finally get the values array
var final = Object.values(obj);
console.log(final);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Note this answer probably has a slight perf advantage over mine since you reduce the number of iterations with the first pass. However, if its worth it depends on if your list is of a trivial size or if its huge. If it was huge, it'd be a job for an indexed database anyway I think.

Comment: I just wanted to see a working snipper :-) Your solution is compact and readable now that you mention.