# Best way to organize data based on same parent ID and how to display it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, react-native

I have data that I need to organize based on the same parent ID. What I need to do is have a list of categories and data with its respective category. Basically a header (category) with buttons (data) under each header. The data is one JSON response and in that response is 4 categories with parent ID: 0 and their respective names and ID. The rest of the response is the data that corresponds to each category. The non category data has a parent ID value that links to the category id value.

I am not sure the best way to organize this data and how to display it. Thanks in advance.

Data:

```
"data": {
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": 62,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "category_name": "Category 1",
                "category_slug": "category1",
            },
            {
                "id": 60,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "category_name": "Category 2",
                "category_slug": "category2",
            },
            {
                "id": 61,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "category_name": "Category 3",
                "category_slug": "category3",
            },
            {
                "id": 59,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "category_name": "Category 4",
                "category_slug": "category4",
            }
            {
                "id": 1,
                "parent_id": 60,
                "category_name": "Button 1",
                "category_slug": "button1",
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "parent_id": 61,
                "category_name": "Button 3",
                "category_slug": "button3",
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "parent_id": 59,
                "category_name": "Button 2",
                "category_slug": "button2",
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "parent_id": 61,
                "category_name": "Button 4",
                "category_slug": "button4",
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "parent_id": 59,
                "category_name": "Button 5",
                "category_slug": "button5",
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "parent_id": 61,
                "category_name": "Button 6",
                "category_slug": "button6",
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "parent_id": 60,
                "category_name": "Button 7",
                "category_slug": "button7",
            },
            {
                "id": 10,
                "parent_id": 62,
                "category_name": "Button 10",
                "category_slug": "button10",
            },
        ]
    },
```

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [List of categories with data based on two array of objects with same parent ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73177640/list-of-categories-with-data-based-on-two-array-of-objects-with-same-parent-id)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temporary `Map` keyed by `id`, and with values the corresponding objects, but each with a `children` property. Then populate those `children` arrays. Finally extract the objects from the `Map`.

To render, you could generate a nested `ul` using a recursive function.

See here:

```js
function transform(categories) {
    const map = new Map(categories.map(({id, parent_id, category_name}) =>
        [id, { category_name, children: [] }]
    )).set(0, { children: [] });

    for (const {id, parent_id} of categories) {
        map.get(parent_id).children.push(map.get(id));
    }

    return [...map.get(0).children];
}

function render(ul, tree) {
    for (const {category_name, children} of tree) {
        const li = document.createElement("li");
        li.textContent = category_name;
        li.appendChild(render(document.createElement("ul"), children));
        ul.appendChild(li);
    }
    return ul;
}

const data = {"categories": [{"id": 62,"parent_id": 0,"category_name": "Category 1","category_slug": "category1",},{"id": 60,"parent_id": 0,"category_name": "Category 2","category_slug": "category2",},{"id": 61,"parent_id": 0,"category_name": "Category 3","category_slug": "category3",},{"id": 59,"parent_id": 0,"category_name": "Category 4","category_slug": "category4",},{"id": 1,"parent_id": 60,"category_name": "Button 1","category_slug": "button1",},{"id": 3,"parent_id": 61,"category_name": "Button 3","category_slug": "button3",},{"id": 2,"parent_id": 59,"category_name": "Button 2","category_slug": "button2",},{"id": 4,"parent_id": 61,"category_name": "Button 4","category_slug": "button4",},{"id": 5,"parent_id": 59,"category_name": "Button 5","category_slug": "button5",},{"id": 6,"parent_id": 61,"category_name": "Button 6","category_slug": "button6",},{"id": 7,"parent_id": 60,"category_name": "Button 7","category_slug": "button7",},{"id": 10,"parent_id": 62,"category_name": "Button 10","category_slug": "button10",},]};

const tree = transform(data.categories);
render(document.querySelector("ul"), tree);
```

```html
<ul></ul>
```